# Trying to change Yocto downloads directory

Tags: configuration, yocto

A while back I installed the Yocto project and built the core-image-sato for the qemu x86. I left the downloads directory as the default build/downloads.

Now I want to build images for the BeagleBone Black. So I decided to move the downloads directory up under /opt/poky/ and edited the BeagleBone Black local.conf file accordingly to set DL_DIR ?= "/opt/poky/downloads". But when I run bitbake core-image-minimal, it creates a downloads directory under my BeagleBone Black build directory and starts getting everything off the net.

I'm running poky krogoth under CentOS 7. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Never mind. Pilot error. I failed to notice that that line of local.conf was commented. Removing the # did the trick.